# How to interrupt a thread with infinite loop and sleep in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, interrupt

i've been fighting with this over few hours now. Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        wscript.setBid(0.30);

        wscript.setServiceMode(WebScript.ServiceMode.ON);

        for(;!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();)
        {               
            Positioning(demandedPosition, maximumBid);
            if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                break;
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        wscript.setServiceMode(ServiceMode.OFF);
        Log("Algorithm has been canceled!");
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        wscript.setServiceMode(ServiceMode.OFF);
        Log("Algorithm has been canceled!");
        return;
    }
```

The thing is, that i would like to interrupt it in legit way with this code:

```
private void StopService()
{
    service.interrupt();
}
```

When I call this method when Thread.sleep() is running, it gets InterruptedException and everything works fine. However, as I call it when the PositioningAlgorithm is running nothing is happenning, the thread acts like it never got the interruption state.
Regards,
DualCore

EDIT: It is essential for me that the call Log("Algorithm has been canceled!"); will be executed after interruption.

SOLVED: I had overwritten `Thread.interrupt()` to edit class local variable which was checked whether the thread is ready to end:

```
service = new Thread(mechanism)
            {
                @Override
                public void interrupt()
                {
                    super.interrupt();
                    mechanism.ReadyToReturn = true;
                }
            };
```

And here's updated thread main algorithm:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        wscript.setBid(0.30);
        wscript.setServiceMode(WebScript.ServiceMode.ON);
        for(;!ReadyToReturn || !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();)
        {               
            Positioning(demandedPosition, maximumBid);
            if(ReadyToReturn || Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                break;
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        wscript.setServiceMode(ServiceMode.OFF);
        Log("Algorithm has been canceled!");

    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        wscript.setServiceMode(ServiceMode.OFF);
        Log("Algorithm has been canceled!");
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that Positioning() doesn't immediately quit, when you call service.interrupt? Or that the condition if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) isn't true, if you call service.interrupt and Positioning() returns?

Comment: Positioning() doesn't immidiately quit when i call this and the condition isn't true after Positioning() returns too.

Comment: Well, it's normal that the `Positioning()` method won't immediately quit if it's in the middle of some work. But you are right to expect the `interrupted` flag to be set, at least.  Can you show us the contents of the `Positioning()` method?  Otherwise, JiriS' answer sounds correct.

Comment: It has 3 classes deep. I mean one is inside another. Too much to check. I think that i will try with ThreadLocal variables(strange thing though, i cant make this work).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why this might be happening is that Positioning clears `isInterrupted` flag (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29) and/or catches somewhere `InterruptedException` (or `Exception`/`Throwable`).

One possibility is to use another flag (e.g. using `volatile` variable/ `AtomicBoolean`/`ThreadLocal`) to indicate whether the thread should be interrupted.

Comment: first paragraph is good, but your second paragraph doesn't make sense. if you can add checking a flag to the Positioning code, it's just as easy to fix the interrupt flag-clearing behavior.

Comment: He's not using `interrupted()` but `isInterrupted()` which doesn't clear the flag. In any case he should use a custom flag. Even a simple volatile boolean would do it. I would avoid `ThreadLocal` though, it makes no sense to use it here. As for @NathanHughes it makes more sense to use an explicit flag, since threads can be interrupted by other code beside the author's.

Comment: @Kayaman: if you have a reference for "since threads can be interrupted by other code beside the author's" I would like to read it.

Comment: @Kayaman: I'm aware of the fact he's not using `interrupted()`, but clearly either `Positioning()` or other code must be calling it.

Comment: @NathanHughes My mistake, I was thinking about spurious wake-ups. Nevertheless it's not a bad idea to use a separate flag to clearly indicate the intent, rather than using "interrupt" as a general exit-flag.